# using a contract in another contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-design, dapps

I have my Callee contract in Callee.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Callee {
  uint private val;

  constructor() public{
    val = 30;
  }
  function getValue() public view returns(uint) {
      return val;
  }
  function increment() public returns(uint) {
    val = val + 1;
    return val;
  }
}
```

and I have another contract Caller.sol where i have to use Callee functions.
should i use inheritance

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
import "./Callee.sol";

contract Caller is Callee{

    // Callee public c;
    // constructor(address addr) public {
    //  c = Callee(addr);
    // }
    function someAction() public returns(uint){
      return getValue();
    }
    function inc() public returns(uint){
      return increment();
    }

}
```

OR should i use contract creation method by new?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
import "./Callee.sol";

contract Caller{

    Callee public c;
    constructor() public {
      c = new Callee();
    }
    function someAction() public view returns(uint){
      return c.getValue();
    }
    function inc() public returns(uint){
      return c.increment();
    }
}
```

also if I am building my ICO dapp where I have two contracts `ERC20Token.sol` and `MYICO.sol` where MYICO will be used to buy token etc.
then which one of the above methods shoild i use to `ERC20Token.sol` from  `MYICO.sol`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about deploying your `Callee` independently and sending that address as constructor parameter when you deploy the `Caller`?

```
contract Caller {
    Callee callee;

    constructor(address _callee) {
        callee = Callee(_callee);
    }
}
```

Does your `Caller` have properties (show behavior) of `Callee` then yes, you can go with inheritance. But, for the ICO your second and the one I gave are the generally used solutions.

`ERC20Token` is the `Callee` and `MYICO` is the `Caller`.

Comment: so, if person A calls to Caller(here msg.sender will be address of A) which in turn calls to Callee, then in Callee msg.sender will be the address of Caller not A. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct. The msg.sender in the Callee will be the Caller and not the A.

Comment: If this answered your query try to upvote it and select this as answer.